# Samsung series 3 runnint ubuntu 12.04, battery indicator does not recognize when I unplug my charger

Tags: 12.04, power-management, battery, samsung

I have a Samsung series 3 (NP305E5A-S01CA) running 12.04, everything has been running great except for the battery and power management programs. Even when my AC charger is unplugged and it is running on battery, it still says charging. Even when I go into settings.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to reset your laptops power management settings. Try the following:

- Disconnect your laptop from the AC adapter
- Remove the battery from the laptop
- Press the power button as if you were trying to turn the laptop on
- Reconnect the battery to the laptop
- Reconnect the AC adaptor to the laptop and make sure it is charging
- Turn the laptop on
- Try disconnecting the AC adaptor and see if the laptop now recognises that it is no longer charging